# Node JS Using Bcrypt.Hash- Password does not get hashed after updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to do a update function for user profiles on the password. I don't know why but the password get hashed perfectly when signing in. However when I set up the update function using route.put, the password does not get hashed. It is still a text when I check on Postman. I would like to hash the password when the users change their passwords in text type. Here is what I did in Routes / API

```
router.put("/:_id", (req, res) => {
var update=req.body
const { errors, isValid } = validateEditProfile(req.body);

if (!isValid) {
return res.status(400).json(errors)
}

User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, update, { new: true })

.then(user =>res.json(user))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ update: false }));
});
```

I have also added some line to hash password but it is still not working.

```
router.put("/:_id", (req, res) => {
var update=req.body
const { errors, isValid } = validateEditProfile(req.body);

if (!isValid) {
return res.status(400).json(errors)
}
var newPassword = req.body.password
bcrypt.hash(newPassword,(hash)=>{
req.body.password=hash
})
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, update, { new: true })

.then(user =>res.json(user))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ update: false }));
 });
```

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your second example is anything to go on then your problem is a misunderstanding of how asynchronous code works in Node.

The result of `hash` won't be returned within the same context as `findIdAndUpdate`, and despite the closure approach, it won't update `req.body.password` in time either.

Couple of ways to solve this, the simplest is to just move `findIdAndUpdate` inside the `hash` callback, this will ensure the hash value is updated beforehand. The other way, given `bcrypt` uses Promises, is to use the `async`/`await` syntax to "wait" for the hash result before calling `findIdAndUpdate` e.g.

```
router.put("/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  var update=req.body
  const { errors, isValid } = validateEditProfile(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
  }
  req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password)
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, update, { new: true })
    .then(user =>res.json(user))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ update: false }));
});
```

*NOTE - async / await doesn't actually wait or block the thread, it's just syntactic sugar for handling Promises*

Comment: @CongMinh great, feel free to upvote & accept the answer if you feel it did the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at my code**

```
// route  get api/users/register
// desc   Register users route 
// access public

router.post("/register",(req,res) => {

const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body)

// check the validation 
if(!isValid){
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
}

User.findOne({ email:req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
        if(user){
            errors.email = "Email already exist"
            return res.status(400).json(errors)
        }else{
            const newUser = new User({
                name : req.body.name,
                email : req.body.email,
                password : req.body.password

            });

            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err,hash) => {
                    if(err){
                        throw err
                    }else{
                        newUser.password = hash;
                        newUser.save()
                            .then(user => res.json(user))
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have no problem with registering, the password get hashed perfectly when users register for accounts. However, I have no idea why it does not get hashed when updating a new password

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    const SALTROUNDS = 10; // or another integer in that ballpark
    const self = this;
    if (!self.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALTROUNDS, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log('salt=>>', salt);
        bcrypt.hash(self.password, salt, null, (error, hash) => {
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            }
            console.log('hash==>', hash);
            self.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```